# How do we know that these limits exist? (proof that uniform convergence is sufficient to preserve continuity.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

We have the following theorem from Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*:

> **7.11 Theorem** Suppose $f_n \to f$ uniformly on a set $E$ in a metric space. Let $x$ be a limit point of $E$, and suppose that
>
> $$\lim_{t \to x} f_n(t)=A_n$$
>
> for $n=1, 2, 3, ...$ Then $\{A_n\}$ converges, and
>
> $$\lim_{t \to x} f(t)= \lim_{n \to \infty} A_n$$

My question is, what if $\lim_{t \to x} f_n(t)=A_n$ doesn't exist for every $n$?

I could see that one of the following might be implied by uniform continuity (though I haven't investigated if any of these are true):

$1)$ There are infinitely many $n$ such that $A_n$ converges

$2)$ There exists some $N$ such that $n\ge N \implies A_n$ converges

And then we could take the subsequence $A_{n_k}$ of the ones that converge, and use $A_{n_k}$ in the theorem; but Rudin does not do this. Can someone please clear the matter up for me?

Comment: The nature of a sequence doesn't change if we modifie a finite number of terms.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Ah thank you! I knew the theorem is supposed to be "If a sequence of functions converges uniformly and each function in the sequence is continous, then the limit function is continous". I was confused that I didn't see any assumptions about such limits existing in this statement of the theorem. But of course, the assumptions of the limits existing is in "each function in the sequence is continous"!